# Processing/PApplet Show or hide a figure based on clicking the mouse

Tags: java, processing

[image: Screenshot of the GUI]

Hi guys. I am a newbie programmer and learning Java with processing.core.PApplet on Eclipse. The project visualizes Earthquakes/Majors Cities/Airports on the google Map. I created a "Control Window" which allows users to toggle on or off markers when they click the square box next to the text. Now my problem is, I want the "green check mark" to show inside the box when user clicks it and vanish when user clicks it again, but I don't know how to do it.
Thank you.

Note: The major methods I have are setUp() ,draw(), mouseClicked() and mouseMoved(). All text,rect, and the check mark was drawn in draw() method. I use the MouseClicked() method to check whether the location where the cursor clicked is inside the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `boolean` variable that stores whether the checkbox should be drawn. Here's a little example:

```
boolean checked = false;

void mouseClicked(){
  checked = !checked;
}

void draw() {

  background(0);

  if (checked) {
    ellipse(50, 50, 20, 20);
  }
}
```

You might also try using a GUI library like [G4P](http://www.lagers.org.uk/g4p/), which has a checkbox component you can use instead of drawing it yourself.

Comment: Cant believe it is so easy to do. Thank you very much. I also looked G4P, but I can't check examples due to my browser security settings. I will give a try on the library after I solve my browser problem. :D